# How to import external library in android studio?

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I struggle to import library 'PageSlidingTapStrip'(https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

I found this question([How to import eclipse library project from github to android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310164/how-to-import-eclipse-library-project-from-github-to-android-studio-project)), and I follow this solution.

cf)I'm using win 8.1 , android studio version 0.3.6

First, build new project like this condition.
[image]

Second, go to File -> New Module click, create new module as android library and make condition like this.( Unchecked create custom launcher icon, activity )

[image]

And this part I got a first question. Which version should I choice version about 'Minimum required SDK' , 'Target SDK', 'Compile with'? Just Follow project version? (image show default value when I create this window first.)

Anyway, I progress under condition ' Minimum required SDK : API 9 / Target SDK : API 19 / Compile with : API 19 '

Third, delete files under 'Project/PageSlidingTabStrip/src/main/' and copy folder&file under external library 'res', 'src', 'AndroidManifest.xml' and move into 'Project/PageSlidingTabStrip/src/main/' then renamed src to java.

And then project & folder become like this. (what I followed question as , told me copy and move file 'ic_launcer-web.png' apart from 'res', 'src', 'manifest' , but I can't find that file)

[image]

Fourth, go to 'File -> Project setting -> Module -> click project module -> '+' button -> select Module dependency' then apply.
[image]

After that, I face this error and cannot resolve R.
[image]
And I can't go next step, can't finish import library.
What should I do?

Is there any other solution?

Thanks for seeing long question. I hope to get a solution!

Comment: There's a "Gradle Console" window you can bring up; there's a button for it in the bottom toolbar on the right-hand side. There will be more error output in that console that will tell you what's going wrong -- it's a collision between the multiple AndroidManfiest.xml files in your combined project. If you can't figure out the solution from that error message, edit your question here and paste the entire contents of that console window after doing a build.

In the next version of Android Studio there are some bug fixes to this error message handling, so it won't be as confusing.

Comment: Yep, as I see 'see console more info', so I click 'gradle console' but nothing is shown.
But I'll try again and quest again...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also use the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` Project in my app and everything works fine.
I'm not sure if it's already possible to add a library project via the IDE (-> without any problems). 
Please try to add the library project by editing the gradle files like this:

- first delete your module `PagerSlidingTabStrip`
- then create a folder in your root project directory (-> `NewOne`) named 'libs'
- copy the complete folder 'library' of the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` project on git into 'libs'
- rename the folder 'library' that you just copied to e.g. "PagerSlidingTabStripLibrary" (just to avoid confusion) -> after the renaming you should have the path: "NewOne/libs/PagerSlidingTabStripLibrary"
- now add this library in your `settings.gradle` with the following command:

  ```
  include ':libs:PagerSlidingTabStripLibrary'
  ```
- go to your `build.gradle` file of your AppProject `aps` and add the following line to your 'dependencies':

  ```
  compile project(':libs:PagerSlidingTabStripLibrary')
  ```
- at least you have to sync your gradle files: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Please try this. If you get errors please post the log file.

Comment: Thanks for giving me answer.
I try to your method.
But something is wrong. I want to show you capture picture but I can't attach. (libs/PagerSlidingTabStripLibrary/src/.... file doesn't recognize java file) Anyway, when I try to 'sync with gradle file', it tolds me 'Gradel 'NewOne' project refresh failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found. '

Comment: You could try this: first close you project, than you should see the "Quick Start" Wizard of AS. Here: open a project, but instead of selecting your project folder select your seetings.gradle file. In the "Import Project from Gradle" you should mark "Use default gradle wrapper" and click ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464758/get-error-when-import-library-in-android-studio

I post again!

Comment: I try again that you told me, using quick start wizard and open project, but similiar things come out. 'Resolve Error, configuration with name 'default' not found' TT

Answer (score 4):

**For update up to Android Studio 1.2.1.1**

There are basically three types of dependencies which we have to add in project of android Studio

**Add Normal Dependencies like Support files**

1. Right click on project->open module settings
2. Select dependencies->Now press **right** "+" icon button ->Select
   library Dependencies
3. Enter Name and Search
4. Select file and press ok button.

**Add Git Hub Dependencies**

Find the dependencies of git repository for example **compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'** from https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

```
A. open build.gradle(module:app) file
B. Add lines compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
```

OR

Follow as describe above in **Normal Dependencies Step** by just enter dependencies in search bar

**Add Jar files Dependencies**

1. Right click on project->open module settings
2. press **left** "+" icon (insert new Module) button -> Select import Jar or .AAR package->browse Jar file and finish
3. Now select dependencies-> press right "+" icon button ->Select module Dependencies->select jar files->press ok button.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I had this problem and eventually solved it by consistently using the same sdk version & build tools across projects.

Comment: Yep I already adjust same version all of them. But it can't solve  T.T

Comment: It was odd for me -- I had to go through all of them to make consistent.  I may have also re-started android studio and then it sort of cleaned itself up.... I wish I had a better suggestion for you!