# Get Error when Import library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to import PagerSlidingTabStrip Library with 2 ways. Using add 'new module' and via IDE.

But both of them cause error like this.

What should I do? To hard to get solution of this..

[image: add new module]

[image: IDE]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: post ur logcat properly...

Comment: Follow the steps outlined as an answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar HTH

Comment: oops sorry I'll post it again.