# How to add module In Android studio

Tags: android

I an Importing module of daimaja AndroidImageSlider library in my Project 
here Is Link https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

existing module name is library .i have already library module name

i change the name module imageslider
and import

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.technosoftera.tradegateway"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':imageslide')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.5.0.jar')
    compile  'com.wunderlist:sliding-layer:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.3@aar' 
}
```

above is my gradle file  i added in dependency

after gradle build failed error occure

```
Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

this Is the Error please help to import this library

Comment: post full gradle please, I think there is a line that starts with: apply from

Comment: If you view the gradle file here -- https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/library/build.gradle  -- it has an extra line in there -- (apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle') -- not sure but maybe you need that plus that file to add your project -- https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/tree/master/library

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/30883950/437703

Answer (score 4):

Put modules inside the Application Project:

```
Right click on Application->Open Module Settings -> Click on the '+' icon ->
Select the root directory for your library module you'd like to add ->
Follow the prompts
```

Then, add it to Application as a library dependency.(Module Settings):

```
 Select your Application module -> Select the Dependencies tab on the right ->
 Click the '+' icon on the bottom -> Select Module Dependency -> Select your 
desired library module
```