# Importing a module into Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Just starting in Android dev, I would like to use [Android Websockets](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets) code in my new project in Android Studio.

OS X 10.8.x, AS 0.4.0

I followed: [How to import eclipse library project from github to android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310164/how-to-import-eclipse-library-project-from-github-to-android-studio-project)

Everything worked great until I tried to actually code. I pasted in (from the example):

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> extraHeaders = Arrays.asList(
    new BasicNameValuePair("Cookie", "session=abcd")
);

WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create("wss://irccloud.com"), new WebSocketClient.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got string message! %s", message));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(byte[] data) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got binary message! %s", toHexString(data)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(int code, String reason) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Disconnected! Code: %d Reason: %s", code, reason));
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error!", error);
    }

}, extraHeaders);

client.connect();

// Later… 
client.send("hello!");
client.send(new byte[] { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF });
client.disconnect();
```

When I build/run the project, I get:

`error: cannot find symbol class WebSocketClient`

I think my question is: What is the `import` statement I should use?

How would I go about adding/using this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran into a bug that was fixed in Android Studio 0.4.3. I recommend you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The auto importer was broken. Once I restarted Android Studio it showed I should put:

`import com.codebutler.android_websockets.WebSocketClient;`

As my import. Now I have a NullPointerException for a particular piece of code, but that's a different problem.