# use chromeview in android studio

Tags: android, google-chrome, virtual-reality

i want to work with web V.R. in android studio. i found that i should use gecko view or chrome view or something like them. but i cant find anything in the web. all the references are belong to eclipse and don't work with android studio. 
alternatively i put my files in external storage and load them with chrome but it didn't work properly.
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.html
https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview
I use these but i cant run my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can import eclipse library project in android studio as well. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20319616/4360419)